# Django url tag : maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling around the following problem:

I've two urls files :

The root one :

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        ...
        (r'^demonstrator/', include('powernest.demonstrator.urls')),
        ...
    )
```

and the application one :

```
    urlpatterns += patterns('demonstrator.views',
        ...
        url(r'^demonstrator/choices/$', 'demo_choices', d_demo_choice, name="demo_choices"),
        ...
    )
```

The associated view :

```
    def demo_choices(request, template_name, action):
        ...
        return render_to_response(template_name, datas, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I try to call the named url "demo_choices" in a template, thanks to {% url demo_choices %} I get a TemplateSyntaxError exception :

**Caught an exception while rendering: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object**

I have spent much time without figuring it out! please help !

Thank you  and sorry for my poor english!

Victor

Comment: Please post the *full* urls.py, especially the application-specific one - you've got a `+=` there, and I'd like to know what is being added.

Answer (score 0):

You are including your app.urls and using `+=` in your app urls.py. This is causing the max recursion depth exceeded errors.

Leave your urls.py as it is and change your app/urls.py to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('demonstrator.views',
    ...
    url(r'^choices/$', 'demo_choices', d_demo_choice,  name="demo_choices"),
    ...
)
```

Note that you don't really need that extra "demonstrator" part in the url regex. Hope that helps.